# Python Unbound error in return statement of a function

Tags: python, speech-recognition, alexa-skills-kit, wikipedia, pyttsx3

I am trying to build an Ai assistant similar to Alexa from this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AWvsXxDtEkU... So, I was getting this error and I can't seem to debug it:

```
line 31, in take_command : return command : UnboundLocalError: local variable 'command' referenced before assignment
```

I know this question has been asked a ton of times but I can't seem to understand the solutions, I've read plenty of articles about an unbound error I know it's an issue of global and local scopes but again the same same thing I can't understand those properly...

Here's my code:

```py
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import pywhatkit
import datetime
import wikipedia
import pyjokes

listener = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)


def talk(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()


def take_command():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print('listening...')
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            command = command.lower()
            if 'alexa' in command:
                command = command.replace('alexa', '')
                print(command)
    except:
        pass
    return command


def run_alexa():
    command = take_command()
    print(command)
    if 'play' in command:
        song = command.replace('play', '')
        talk('playing ' + song)
        pywhatkit.playonyt(song)
    elif 'time' in command:
        time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%I:%M %p')
        talk('Current time is ' + time)
    elif 'who the heck is' in command:
        person = command.replace('who the heck is', '')
        info = wikipedia.summary(person, 1)
        print(info)
        talk(info)
    elif 'date' in command:
        talk('sorry, I have a headache')
    elif 'are you single' in command:
        talk('I am in a relationship with wifi')
    elif 'joke' in command:
        talk(pyjokes.get_joke())
    else:
        talk('Please say the command again.')


while True:
    run_alexa()
```

I hope you can help me fix this mess... Thanks

Comment: If an exception occurs before you assign `command`, you can't `return command`

Comment: Give `command` default value before the `try`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line 31, `return command` will never be reached if you run into an exception. You have to put the return statement within the try block.

```py
def take_command():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print('listening...')
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            command = command.lower()
            if 'alexa' in command:
                command = command.replace('alexa', '')
                print(command)
        return command
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Error:   File "c:/Users/anand59/Desktop/JARVIS/main.py", line 59, in <module>
    run_alexa()
  File "c:/Users/anand59/Desktop/JARVIS/main.py", line 36, in run_alexa
    if 'play' in command:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Comment: @Saumya Your error will tell you what's wrong with your code. It's saying `TypeError: ... 'NoneType' is not iterable`. `command` has to be an iterable object because you are using `if 'play' in command`, but because `command` is None, it errors out. Find out why it's returning None and go from there.